# Ivy fails to resolve a dependency whereas it works with maven

Tags: maven, ivy, nexus

Me as a *Maven* newbie, I am playing around with my own local [Sonartype Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). I have configured my maven installation to use it as a proxy and it works fine for a simple test project in resolving the following dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Next, I tried a similar project with *Ivy* having

in the `ivy.xml` . Ivy is using the same Nexus server as proxy (configured in  `ivysettings.xml` )

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default"/>
    <property name="m2-pattern" value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" override="false" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="default">
            <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" root="http://localhost:2281/nexus/content/groups/public"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

However, when running ant, it fails to resolve `hibernate-validator-4.2.0-Final`

```
[ivy:retrieve]
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]          module not found: org.hibernate#com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator;4.2.0.Final
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://localhost:2281/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate.validat
or/4.2.0.Final/com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator-4.2.0.Final.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact org.hibernate#com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator;4.2.0.Final!com.springsource.org.hi
bernate.validator.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    http://localhost:2281/nexus/content/groups/public/org/hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate.validat
or/4.2.0.Final/com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
[ivy:retrieve]          [NOT FOUND  ] javax.activation#activation;1.0.2!activation.jar (0ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://localhost:2281/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/activation/activation/1.0.2/activation-1.0.2.j
ar
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: org.hibernate#com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator;4.2.0.Final: not found
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: javax.activation#activation;1.0.2!activation.jar
```

I already tried to add more remote repositories to the Nexus installation, such as SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository
(http://maven.springframework.org/release/) or JBoss public (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/)
but this did not help.

In principle, Ivy seems to work as well as it fetches a lot of other dependencies before failing.

My questions:
1) Why does Maven not fail for the same reason? Is hibernate-validator kind of optional and Ivy has another resolve strategy as Maven?

2) I am curious about the artifact name it tries to resolve: `org.hibernate#com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator;4.2.0.Final`
   (BTW if I add `<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-validator" rev="4.2.0.Final" />` it works, but for the Spring case,
   it requires artifact `com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is that I missed to assign all the new repositories (spring, jboss) to the public group repository `/nexus/content/groups/public` which actually was given as only repository in `ivysettings.xml`.